# XPath - Как выбрать только один элемент, который следует за параграфом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, python-3.7, scrapy

```
In [78]: example = response.css("#example")                                                                                                                                   

In [79]: len(example.css("p")[0].xpath(".//following-sibling::div"))                                                                                                          
Out[79]: 100
```

Как нужно мне прописать XPath, чтобы получить только следующий див, один, а не все дивы, которые идут до конца страницы?

`example.css("p")` т.е. я вот выбрал все параграфы и теперь хочу получить див после первого, второго, третьего и т.д. параграфа.

`example.css("p")[0]` - беру первый параграф и прописываю XPath `.xpath(".//following-sibling::div"))`  а оно выбирает все дивы.

А мне нужен только один див, который идет за параграфом.
Конечно можно было бы прописать `[0]`, но это не вариант.

Спасибо.

Comment: len(example.css("p")[0].xpath("(.//following-sibling::div)[1]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите извлечь только первый элемент, вы можете вызвать селектор `.get()` (или его псевдоним, `.extract_first()`обычно используемый в предыдущих версиях Scrapy)

+
Если элемент существует, но не содержит текста (т.е. нет текста):

```
response.css('img::text').getall()
[]
```

`.get()`может вернуть None, даже если элемент существует. Используйте, `default=''`если вы всегда хотите строку:

```
response.css('img::text').get()
response.css('img::text').get(default='')
''
```

Comment: Изивините, я хочу выбрать икспасом один див элемент, которые следует за параграфом.

Comment: Cкиньте HTML или страничку, где Вам нужно выбрать икспасом один див элемент, которые следует за параграфом.